# Seeking References for Visual Verification of Dirichlet Regions in Triangle Groups

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm self-studying the impact of base point placement on the shape of Dirichlet regions within triangle groups. Theoretical findings suggest the region is a quadrilateral when the base point lies on a triangle's edge, and a hexagon when it's inside the triangle.

Are there any visual demonstrations or computational confirmations of this behavior? I'd appreciate pointers to any such prior work, as well as recommendations for tools that could help in illustrating these geometric properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "theoretical findings"? In math one either has a proof or one does not.